# How to move Datatable Select to the Another Header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable and I clone the header and used the second header to put search bar and select option. But the select goes to the top area not in the area I want to put it. I try to change the script but it never change position.

The following image below show the my output during my development.

How to move and align the select to the input search?

[image]

```js
        $("#example tfoot th").each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" style="width:100%" />');
        });

        $("#example thead tr").clone(true).appendTo( "#example thead" );
        $("#example thead tr:eq(1) th").each( function (i) {
            var title = $(this).text();   
            $(this).html( '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" style="width:100%" />' );
     
            $( "input", this ).on( "keyup change", function () {
                if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                    table
                        .column(i)
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0, 6],
                "orderable": false,
            }, ],
            "responsive": true,
            "orderCellsTop": true,
            "fixedHeader": true
        });

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;
            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });

        //Header
        table.column(1).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });
        
        table.column(2).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });

        table.column(5).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });

        //Footer
        table.column(1).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });

        table.column(2).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });

        table.column(5).every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control" style="width:100%"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search(val ?   '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered responsive nowrap" id="example" width="100%">    
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th width="3%">No</th>
            <th width="30%">Machine</th>
            <th width="15%">Spec1</th>
            <th width="15%">Spec2</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec3</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec4</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec5</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec6</th>
            <th width="6%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th width="3%">No</th>
            <th width="30%">Machine</th>
            <th width="15%">Spec1</th>
            <th width="15%">Spec2</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec3</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec4</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec5</th>
            <th width="6%">Spec6</th>
            <th width="6%">Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo showing how to add a mixture of input fields and selects (drop-downs) to the second header row:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>

<script>

var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );

  $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
 
    $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
      if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
        table.column(i).search( this.value ).draw();
      }
    } );
  } );
 
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { data: "name" },
      { data: "position" },
      { data: "office" },
      { data: "extn" },
      { data: "start_date" },
      { data: "salary" }
    ],
    orderCellsTop: true,
    fixedHeader: true,

    initComplete: function () {
      this.api().columns([1,2]).every( function () {
        var column = this;
        //console.log( column.index() );
        var nodeBelow = $(column.header()).closest('tr').next().children().eq( column.index() );
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(nodeBelow).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
              var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
              column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
            } );
        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
          select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
      } );
    }

  } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It uses data provided in the demo code, so you would need to remove that for your actual table, and then add any additional features you are using, but which I have not included in my demo.

The main points to note are:

***For the input fields:***

These are created before the DataTable is initialized, after creating the extra header `<tr>` row.  The code creates an input field for *every* column - and then later on we will overwrite those which we want to replace with a dropdown.

The jQuery selector `$('#example thead tr:eq(1) th')` ensures the input fields are placed in the second header row.

The DataTables option `orderCellsTop: true` ensure the sorting functionality is in the first header row, so that the two sets of events - filtering and sorting - are kept separate.

***For the select (drop-down) fields:***

These need access to the data in the table, after the table has been initialized. We therefore build these in an `initComplete` function.

We only create these drop-downs for two of our columns: `this.api().columns([1,2])`.

The DataTables `column.header()` API function allows us to find the top header cell for each column. But we want the second header cell - the one immediately below that. We therefore use this selector to get that cell:

```
$(column.header()).closest('tr').next().children().eq( column.index() );
```

Now we can add the drop-down to that cell.

---

You sholuld be able to use the above techniques to simplify your own code, and avoid a lot of the repetition in it.